# Can a Symfony 2 Action be made initially accessible only from another Action?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I struggled to express what I mean in the title of the question! I'll do my best to make more sense here...

Symfony 2.7

I have a Form, which when it is submitted and successfully validated I would like to feed into a second, independent Form, for further user activity.  I would like initial values in the second form to be provided by the first, but that second form then to be independent, e.g. it can go through its own separate submission/validation steps.

I do not want:

- it to be possible for a user to go straight to the second form
- to have to pass values for the second form as querystring parameters
- to use Javascript to achieve this
- to persist data to a DB in the first form and pick it up in the second

Conceptually, I would like to be able to validate the first form, and then in the Controller to pass the data received to a different Action, which would show the new Form to the user.  Further user submissions would then be handled by the new Action.  I feel like this should be possible, I'm just not sure how to make it happen!  In a way I'd like the second Action to be private, but it does need to be public so that the second form can be submitted.  I'd like to be able to pass data to the second Action directly using an object, but I don't want to expose that entry point as a standard Route.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when the first form `isValid()` then write a session variable containing your desired values. at the top of the second action, check for required session vars and if not present or valid, then redirect back to first.

Comment: I don't quiet get it but is this what you want? [Forwarding a request from one controller method to another controller method](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ci2p/forwarding-a-request-from-one-controller-method-to-another-controller-method)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I think they're both helpful and if you post them as Answers I'll upvote.  I'm also going to post what I actually did in the end, which isn't the same but isn't a million miles away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for any lack of clarity in the question.  Here's how I solved it (I'd still be interested in any different/better solutions):

I created a separate FormType (`ReportConfirmType`) and Action (`ConfirmAction`) for the second step.  `ReportConfirmType` has the type of Data Class, and essentially all the same fields as the original FormType (`ReportType`), but with them all marked `readonly`.  The route is very similar.  I also created a private method to act as the "glue" between the first and second steps.

When I'm finished with my first step, I then call the private method, passing it the validated data from the first step (which can be used unchanged).  This method sets up the second form and returns the second view.  The action of the form needs to be changed to that of the second route.

All subsequent submissions will go to the new route, and when the second form validates I can carry out the final activities of the process.

Here's some example code to illustrate further:

*ReportType*

```
class ReportType extends AbstractType{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('completedBy', 'text')
        ->add('comments', 'textarea', ['required' => false])
        ->add('format', 'choice', ['choices' => ['pdf' => 'PDF', 'word' => 'MS Word'] ])
        ->add('save', 'submit', ['label' => 'Submit', 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']])
        ->getForm();
}

...
```

*ReportConfirmType*

```
class ReportConfirmType extends AbstractType{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', ['attr' => ['readonly' => 'readonly']])
        ->add('completedBy', 'text', ['attr' => ['readonly' => 'readonly']])
        ->add('comments', 'textarea', ['required' => false, 'attr' => ['readonly' => 'readonly']])
        ->add('format', 'choice', ['choices' => ['pdf' => 'PDF', 'word' => 'MS Word'], 'attr' => ['readonly' => 'readonly'] ])
        ->add('agree', 'checkbox', ['mapped' => false, 'label' => 'I agree', 'constraints' => [new IsTrue()]])
        ->add('save', 'submit', ['label' => 'Submit', 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']])
        ->getForm();
}

...
```

*ReportController*

```
class ReportController extends Controller
{

public function indexAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ReportType(), new ReportDetails() );

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        return $this->confirmPseudoAction($id, $form);
    }

    return $this->render('Bundle:Report:index.html.twig', ['form'=> $form->createView()]);
}

private function confirmPseudoAction($id, \Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form)
{
    $action = $this->generateUrl('form_confirm_report', ['id' => $id]);
    $confirmForm = $this->createForm(new ReportConfirmType(), $form->getData(), ['action' => $action]);

    return $this->render('Bundle:Report:confirm.html.twig', ['form'=> $confirmForm->createView()]);
}

public function confirmAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ReportConfirmType(), new ReportDetails() );

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        return $this->generateReport($id, $form->getData());
    }

    return $this->render('Bundle:Report:confirm.html.twig', ['form'=> $form->createView()]);
}

...
```

*routing.yml*

```
form_report:
    path: /form/{id}/report
    defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Report:index }
    requirements:
        id:  \d+

form_confirm_report:
    path: /form/{id}/reportConfirm
    defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Report:confirm }
    requirements:
        id:  \d+
```

And this does what I want! There may be an easier way, but I've done it now...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use dynamic generation for submitted forms.
[It allows you to customize the form specific to the data that was submitted by the user](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms)

Comment: You can, but I don't want to do that in this case.  Or, rather, my question is about a different approach.  I have another question more related to that, if you like...: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297029/non-javascript-confirm-step-for-symfony-form